# Calling user defined function

Tags: sql

I have a function called get_distance(point1,point2) which calculates the distance between the two points. I want to calculate the distance between the point in the top row of the column (points) of my table (geometry) and an already defined variable (point_variable). I am running the following query which fails to terminate:

```
-- Assume point_variable has already been defined as a varchar and 
-- has a value
-- Assume that there is a column (points) in my table 
-- (geometry) with only points stored as varchar
-- Also, assume that there is a scalar function (get_distance) that 
-- takes as input two points (as 2 varchar parameters)and computes 
-- and returns the distance as an int
SELECT get_distance(point_variable, (SELECT TOP 1 points from 
geometry))
```

I am running the previous code and the query never terminates. My goal is to get the distance between the entry in the top row of the points column and the variable point_variable. How should I try to resolve this problem?

Comment: When you ask an SQL question, please identify which DBMS you're using.  The answers vary between DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare your query results to a variable, then pass that to the function:

```
    DECLARE @POINTS_VAR VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @POINTS_VAR = (SELECT TOP 1 points from geometry)
    SELECT get_distance(point_variable, @POINTS_VAR)
```